# visual studio 2010 remote debugging: start external program: directory does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

Everything works if I do "Attach To Process".

But I need to debug a problem during launch of an application, so I need to be able to either "Start project" or "Start external program" the remote exe.

When I do, I get "directory does not exist". (Presumably, It is either looking for this non-existent directory LOCALLY, or it lacks permissions.)

Details:
* .Net Framework 3.5; C# Windows Form, with button that when clicked does

```
Debug.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

- Two Windows 7 Ultimate PCs, with same username and password, administrator.

Local PC:

- Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Hello World project open and built.
  Tested locally: Start Debugging / hit button / see "Hello World!" in VS Output pane.
  Quit local version of app.

Remote PC:

- Visual "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable" installed (so can run a debug version of this .Net application; before installing said "The program can't start because MSVCR100.dll is missing, when hit a breakpoint.").
- Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor running.

  - says "(date/time) Msvsmon started a new server named Steve@FRESHINSTALL: Waiting for new connections".
  - When Attach to Process, says "FreshInstall\Steve connected".
- Copy from local pc's project location (in default VS 2010 projects), \bin\debug* to C:\Code\HelloWorld*
- Code folder is Shared with full privileges (just in case ...)

Attach to Process works fine:

- click button => "Hello World" -- in Local PC's Output pane, just like when running locally.

---

Now, the problem. How LAUNCH the .exe remotely, instead of Attach to Process?

On Debug pane:

- Tried "Start project"
- alternatively, tried "Start external program:" C:\Code\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.exe" -- on Remote PC, this is the path to .exe
- Working directory: "C:\Code\HelloWorld"  <-- this directory ONLY exists on Remote PC (deliberately -- to make sure we aren't executing locally)
- [checkmark] Use remote machine: FRESHINSTALL.
- Tried with and without "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".

When do "Start Debugging", all variations say "The working directory does not exist: "C:\Code\HelloWorld".

Well, of course not: it is on Remote PC, not locally.

Yet everywhere I look, this is what instructions say to do.

What am I supposed to do differently, or what could be wrong?

---

(Obviously this simple app, I could stick with Attach To Process. But I have a MUCH more complicated multiple-dll application, which is having a problem during startup. I need to breakpoint the "real" application during its start up, not after it is already running.)

(And the real situation I have to debug, is on the other side of the world, with a slow internet link. This is a local simulation of what is going wrong there. Not practical to install visual studio on the actual remote PC, to turn it into a local debugging situation. Spent a day trying to remote debug that; after I get it working on a local network, I have to duplicate the whole process with much less control over what is going on.)

Comment: check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923695/visual-studio-remote-upload-and-debugging-on-other-computer/11924679#11924679
this enables you to do exactly what you want to do

this assumes you can modify the code running on the remote pc - can you?

Comment: also if you read that link...you dont need to use remcom... assuming you make the code changes you can simply re-deploy your app and start it on the remote pc with the `debug` arg then it will hang until your debugger connects from your local PC

Comment: @wal - thanks, I will give that a try. At minimum, that will let me know if the start up is reaching the main method, or I have some more fundamental dll problem.  Turning it into an "Attach to Process" approach is clever!

Comment: have you checked the event viewer on the remote PC? may shed some light if app does not make it to main

Comment: @wal Thx. Whole separate topic of configuring for more information, if that happens.  On Hello World, those 5 lines of code worked perfectly: am now sitting on the Debugger.Break(); line.  So, THIS step of my debugging is solved.  Now I just have to take the REAL app, and get it to this point, then I am in territory I know how to handle. Thanks again.

Comment: Its amazing how much pain a small bit of code can avoid, when a person who knows takes the time to share that insight!

Comment: stoked for you! dont forget that code should always check for `debug` to avoid 'leaving' it in for production code. i add my first comment as an answer if suits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interests of closing this question, to indicate that it has been addressed:

See wal's first comment on my question, and follow the link he gave, which I repeat here:

[Visual Studio remote upload and debugging on other computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923695/visual-studio-remote-upload-and-debugging-on-other-computer/11924679#11924679)